# Jqgrid Inline Error Handler file Not found while Using it with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, jqgrid-asp.net

I am using Jqgrid for inline editing with asp.net and using a handler.ashx file for storing values from the grid. It is working perfectly fine in my VS but when i publish and run it on iis it trows error.

following is the code for jqgrid

```
$("#grid-table-Labor").jqGrid({
                    url: 'LaborApproval.aspx/GetLaborData', //asp function to get all data from data base to grid 
                    data: "{}",
                    datatype: 'json',
                    mtype: 'POST',
                    serializeGridData: function (postData) {
                        return JSON.stringify(postData);
                    },
                    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
                    loadonce: true,
                    colNames: [' ', 'Employee Code', 'Name', 'Contractor', 'DOJ', 'Police Verification', 'Gate Pass Valid Upto', 'Status', 'Remark'],
                    colModel: [
                                    {
                                        name: 'myac', index: 'myac', width: 80, fixed: true, sortable: false, resize: false, formatter: 'actions',
                                        formatoptions: {
                                            keys: true,
                                            delbutton: false,
                                            editOptions: {},
                                            addOptions: {},
                                            delOptions: {}
                                        }
                                    },
                                    { name: 'EMPCODE', index: 'EMPCODE', width: 108, key: true },
                                    { name: 'NAME', index: 'NAME', width: 140 },
                                    { name: 'CONTNAME', index: 'CONTNAME', width: 160 },
                                    { name: 'DOJ', index: 'DOJ', width: 70, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd-m-y' } },
                                    { name: 'POLICE_VRIFICATION', index: 'POLICE_VRIFICATION', width: 124 },
                                    { name: 'GatePassValidUpto', index: 'GatePassValidUpto', editable: true, sorttype: "date", unformat: pickDate },
                                    { name: 'Approve', index: 'Approve', width: 148, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "True:Approve;False:Rejected" } },
                                    { name: 'REMARK', index: 'REMARK', width: 150, sortable: false, editable: true, edittype: "textarea", editoptions: { rows: "2", cols: "10" } }
                    ],
                    pager: '#grid-pager-Labor',
                    altRows: true,
                    //cacheUrlData: true,
                    //toppager: true,
                    rowNum: 10,
                    scrollOffset: 0, // to remove offset of scroll bar for imporved gui
                    rowList: [10, 50, 100, 200, 300, 500, 800, 1000, 1500],
                    //onSelectRow: editRow,
                    viewrecords: true,
                    emptyrecords: "Nothing to display",
                    //multiselect: true,
                    //multiboxonly: false,
                    gridview: true,
                    loadComplete: function () {
                        var table = this;
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            //styleCheckbox(table);
                            //updateActionIcons(table);
                            updatePagerIcons(table);
                            enableTooltips(table);
                        }, 0);
                    },
                    jsonReader: {
                        page: function (obj) { return 1; },
                        total: function (obj) { return 1; },
                        records: function (obj) { return obj.d.length; },
                        root: function (obj) { return obj.d; },
                        repeatitems: false,
                        id: "0"
                    },                    
                    editurl: 'Handler/JQGridHandler.ashx',
                    caption: 'Labor List',
                    shrinkToFit: true,
                    height: 'auto',
                    //autowidth: true,
                    xmlReader: {
                        root: "list",
                        row: "Response",
                        id: "cfgId",
                        repeatitems: false
                    },
                    beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {

                        var iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($(e.target).closest("td")[0]);
                        if (this.p.colModel[iCol].name === 'EMPCODE') {                                                       
                            var param = { param: rowid };

                            console.log(rowid);
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "LaborApproval.aspx/ShowMe",                                
                                data: JSON.stringify(param),
                                dataType: "json",
                                type: "POST",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                         
                                success: function (data) {
                                    console.log(data);                                                                            
                                            var box = bootbox.dialog({
                                                    show: true,
                                                    message: data['d'],
                                                    title: "Labour Details",
                                                    buttons: {
                                                        ok: {
                                                            label: "OK",
                                                            className: "btn-primary",
                                                            callback: function() {
                                                                console.log('OK Button');
                                                            }
                                                        }                                   
                                                    }
                                            });
                                            box.modal('show');
                                        },
                                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    var err = eval("(" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ")");
                                    alert(err.Message)
                                    // console.log("Ajax Error!");  
                                }
                            });

                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

and following is the error

```
[HttpException]: The file &#39;/CMS/Web_Pages/HR_Pages/Handler/JQGridHandler.ashx&#39; does not exist.

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)

   at System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory.System.Web.IHttpHandlerFactory2.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

-->
```

Comment: Does that file exist on your IIS?

Comment: yes it does in handler folder

Comment: What is the name of the file there @Lord_of_Lucifer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just had to put

```
editurl: '../../Handler/JQGridHandler.ashx',
```

before the link